# LinkedIn ugcPosts Statistics

Tags: linkedin

Is it possible to retrieve ugc Post analytics similar to the organization share statistics api

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity={organization URN}
```

I have this ugcPost: urn:li:ugcPost:6588481880721633280

Attempted to access the statistics using the ugc id but maintaining a share urn:

```
14:21:17.487 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "{"message":"Unable to get activityIds from any of the given shares. Either the shares/ugcPosts do not have corresponding activities or the organizational entity did not post them.","status":404}"
14:21:17.487 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-0: Close connection
14:21:17.488 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Connection discarded
14:21:17.489 [main] DEBUG com.codahale.metrics.httpclient.InstrumentedHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://api.linkedin.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 1024; total allocated: 0 of 1024]

url: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn:li:organization:10874981&shares[0]=urn:li:share:6588481880721633280&timeIntervals.timeGranularityType=DAY&timeIntervals.timeRange.start=1570216877135, detailMessage: 404 Not Found headers: [.....], responseBody: {"message":"Unable to get activityIds from any of the given shares. Either the shares/ugcPosts do not have corresponding activities or the organizational entity did not post them.","status":404}, responseStatusLine: Not Found, responseCode: 404

    at com.lithium.bandolier.retrofit.LithiumErrorHandler.handleError(LithiumErrorHandler.java:35)
```

The above result suggested that the api may in fact support ugcPosts since the error message contained  "share/ugcPosts", so attempted with a ugcPost urn next and:

```
14:16:03.295 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "{"message":"Array parameter 'shares' value 'urn:li:ugcPost:6588481880721633280' is invalid. Reason: Deserializing output 'urn:li:ugcPost:6588481880721633280' failed","status":400}"
14:16:03.295 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-0: Close connection
14:16:03.296 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Connection discarded
14:16:03.296 [main] DEBUG com.codahale.metrics.httpclient.InstrumentedHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://api.linkedin.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 1024; total allocated: 0 of 1024]

url: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn:li:organization:10874981&shares[0]=urn:li:ugcPost:6588481880721633280&timeIntervals.timeGranularityType=DAY&timeIntervals.timeRange.start=1570216562816, detailMessage: 400 Bad Request headers: [......], responseBody: {"message":"Array parameter 'shares' value 'urn:li:ugcPost:6588481880721633280' is invalid. Reason: Deserializing output 'urn:li:ugcPost:6588481880721633280' failed","status":400}, responseStatusLine: Bad Request, responseCode: 400

    at com.lithium.bandolier.retrofit.LithiumErrorHandler.handleError(LithiumErrorHandler.java:35)
```

Any guidance on how to get basic post engagement data similar to share statistics for ugcPosts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just came across your issue (while facing the same :D )
You have to use the query parameter `ugcPosts` to make it work.

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn:li:organization:12XXXXX&ugcPosts=urn:li:ugcPost:661228XXXX'
```